# Matlab code crashing unexpectedly

Tags: matlab

Does anyone of you have a clue of why the following code is crashing with `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.` error for `N_SUBJ = 17` or `N_SUBJ = 14`, but not for example for the values `13,15,16`?

```
N_PICS = 7
COLR = hsv; 
N_COLR = size(COLR,1); 
COLR = COLR(1+[0:(N_PICS-1)]*round(N_COLR/N_PICS),:);
SUBJ_COLR = hsv; 
N_SUBJ_COLR = size(SUBJ_COLR,1); 
SUBJ_COLR = SUBJ_COLR(1+[0:(N_SUBJ-1)]*round(N_SUBJ_COLR/N_SUBJ),:);
```

And also, could somebody please explain me what it's doing exactly and how it's working?

Comment: "Crashing" is not descriptive. What happens? What is the full error message?

Comment: @horchler - actually it is descriptive cause this code is autocontained. Just run it to see the error message... Anyways it is `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`

Comment: Nope. That would assume that when I run your code I see the exact same thing as you. With different OSes and Matlab versions and OPs not always posting all of the relevant parts there can be no way of know if two people are seeing the same thing. Even if I do run it and get an error, how am I to know if it's the same one? Things can be workspace dependent as well. I've been on too many wild goose chases that I don't always want to try to guess at what someone may be experiencing. Plus, at the time I posted my comment I wasn't at a computer with Matlab accessible, yet another reason.

Comment: @horchler - I agree with you, however it is a simple out of bound mistake, only for this reason I didn't think of posting it. I'll correct it!

Answer (score 1):

When you say crashing, I assume you mean you are seeing the error, `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`? If you are seeing this error then the matrix returned by `hsv` does not have enough rows for the sub-sample operation you are doing.

```
SUBJ_COLR = SUBJ_COLR(1+[0:(N_SUBJ-1)]*round(N_SUBJ_COLR/N_SUBJ),:);
```

selects a subset of the original matrix. `1+[0:(N_SUBJ-1)]*round(N_SUBJ_COLR/N_SUBJ)` calculates which row to select, and `:` means all columns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and yes, that's exactly the message I'm observing, however my question is why does it crash for certain values and for others not. Any clue about that??

Answer (score 1):

The matrix `SUBJ_COLR` is 64-by-3, thus `N_SUBJ_COLR` is equal to 64. You're indexing into the 64 rows of `SUBJ_COLR` and in some cases the particular index is greater than the number of row, resulting in a `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.` error. So the question is really why does this snippet

```
1+[0:(N_SUBJ-1)]*round(N_SUBJ_COLR/N_SUBJ)
```

evaluate to numbers greater than 64 for some values of `N_SUBJ`? This expression can be rewritten as:

```
1+(0:round(64/N_SUBJ):round(64/N_SUBJ)*(N_SUBJ-1))
```

or

```
1:round(64/N_SUBJ):round(64/N_SUBJ)*(N_SUBJ-1)+1
```

where I've replaced `N_SUBJ_COLR` by 64 for clarity. This latter expression more clearly shows what the largest index in the vector will be and how it depends on the value of `N_SUBJ`. You can print out this largest index as a function of `N_SUBJ`:

```
N_SUBJ = 1:30;
round(64./N_SUBJ).*(N_SUBJ-1)+1
```

which returns

```
ans =

  Columns 1 through 13

     1    33    43    49    53    56    55    57    57    55    61    56    61

 Columns 14 through 26

    66    57    61    65    69    55    58    61    64    67    70    73    51

  Columns 27 through 30

    53    55    57    59
```

As you can see, there are several values that exceed 64. This nonlinear behavior comes down to the use of `round`. The integers created by the `round` part don't appear to get small enough fast enough as they multiply `(N_SUBJ-1)` which is growing in order to keep the total term less than 64. One option might be to replace `round` with [`floor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html), but there are probably other ways.